# REST Token based Authentication not working

Tags: java, web-services, rest, annotations, restful-authentication

I am trying to implement Token based authentication in java RESTful web service.

So far I have done following things
1) Created NameBinding secured

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Secured { }
```

2) Created a authentication filter

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // Get the HTTP Authorization header from the request
        String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // Check if the HTTP Authorization header is present and formatted correctly 
        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization header must be provided");
        }

        // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
        String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();

        try {

            // Validate the token
            validateToken(token);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }
    }

    private void validateToken(String token) throws Exception {
        // Check if it was issued by the server and if it's not expired
        // Throw an Exception if the token is invalid
    }
```

3) Now When I am trying to put secured annotation on my service method somehow it is not working and correct json is returned.

```
@GET
@Secured
@Path("{custid}/invoices")
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

public List<Document> getCustomerInvoices(
        @PathParam("custid") String account,
        @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("fromdate") String fromDate,
        @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("todate") String toDate) throws Exception{
Date from = null;
Date to = null;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
if(!fromDate.equals(""))
{
    from = formatter.parse(fromDate);
}

if(!toDate.equals(""))
{
    to = formatter.parse(toDate);
}

ArrayList<Document> invoices = (ArrayList<Document>) CustomerBiz.getInvoices(documentumConfigUtil,DocumentType.TAX_INVOICE,account,from,to);
return  invoices;
}
```

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong.

Note: I have used Apache CXF and spring to create java web service.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue. Actually the problem was in my beans.xml

I used following lines to fix the problem

```
<jaxrs:server id="CustomerResource" address="/customers">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="customerResource" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
            <ref bean='authenticationFilter' />
        </jaxrs:providers>

    </jaxrs:server>
```